# Minimize the volume bounded by a plane

Tags: optimization

A plane passes through the point $(a, b, c)$. Find its intercepts with the coordinate axes if the volume of solid bounded by the plane and the coordinates planes is to be a minimum.

What I have tried: Let $\langle x,y,z \rangle$  be the normal vector of the plane. Then, after some calculation, the volume of the solid is$$V=\frac{(ax+by+cz)^{3}}{2xyz}$$

And I found all the first order derivatives, but I can't find the stationary point. How can I do this? Am I using the wrong approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $a,b,c > 0$, you may also assume $x,y,z \geq 0$ and $xyz=1$.

Then, by the AM-GM inequality:

$$(ax+by+cz)^3 \geq 27(axbycz) = 27 abc.$$
Equality happens iff $ax=by=cz$, or :
$$ (x,y,z) = \frac{1}{(abc)^2}\left(bc,ac,ab\right).$$